# ISSUE IN GPIO PIN INTERRUPT in LPC 1837

Tags: c, embedded

I am using the following code, which main theme is to generate a pin interrupt in lpc 1837, I am facing trouble in getting interrupt,  Anybody give suggestion what went wrong in this code
Compiler: Keil

```
/* Configure pin as digital input using GPIO in pin multiplexing */

GPIO_SetDir(6,0,GPIO_DIR_INPUT);
GPIO_SetDir(6,2,GPIO_DIR_INPUT); 

SCU_PinConfigure(0xC,1,( SCU_CFG_MODE_FUNC4 | SCU_SFS_EPUN | SCU_SFS_ZIF ));
SCU_PinConfigure(0xC,3,( SCU_CFG_MODE_FUNC4 | SCU_SFS_EPUN | SCU_SFS_ZIF )); 


/* enable edge interrupt */ 


LPC_GPIO_PIN_INT->ISEL = 0x00UL; 

/* enable rising edge interrupt */

LPC_GPIO_PIN_INT->IENR = (GPIO_PIN_INT_IENR_ENRL0_Msk |
                          GPIO_PIN_INT_IENR_ENRL1_Msk );

LPC_GPIO_PIN_INT->SIENR = (GPIO_PIN_INT_SIENR_SETENRL0_Msk |
                           GPIO_PIN_INT_SIENR_SETENRL1_Msk );   

/* enable falling edge interrupt */

LPC_GPIO_PIN_INT->IENF = (GPIO_PIN_INT_IENF_ENAF0_Msk |
                          GPIO_PIN_INT_IENF_ENAF0_Msk);

LPC_GPIO_PIN_INT->SIENF = (GPIO_PIN_INT_SIENF_SETENAF0_Msk |
                           GPIO_PIN_INT_SIENF_SETENAF1_Msk );

/* Clear pending interrupt of pin interrupt 1*/

NVIC->ICPR[(((uint32_t)(int32_t)(0x21)) >> 5UL)] = (uint32_t)(1UL << (((uint32_t)(int32_t)(0x21)) & 0x1FUL));

/* set priority for pin interrupt 1 */


NVIC_SetPriority(0x21, 1);  

/* enable pin interrupt */


NVIC->ISER[(((uint32_t)(int32_t)(0x21)) >> 5UL)] = (uint32_t)(1UL << (((uint32_t)(int32_t)(0x21)) & 0x1FUL));
```

Comment: Those casts are nonsense, start by cleaning up that mess. It is obvious that you are just guessing about how type promotions in C work. Might want to read up about "integer promotion" and "balancing/the usual arithmetic conversions" instead of guessing.

Comment: All the registers are setting properly, my issue is when interrupt is occurs, it is not hitting the ISR, Interrupt enable is verified in the NVIC.

Comment: this is driver code.. instead of 0x21, i have to place a variable, so there casts are placed. for testing purpose, i used the value directly..

Comment: Simply do `NVIC->ICPR[(uint32_t)x >> 5] = (1u << ((uint32_t)x & 0x1Fu));`. Or better yet, split that expression in several.

Comment: I tried as you suggested..

Comment: but it is not setting the Interrupt status register IST, tried with edge and level interrupt..

Comment: Can u check the Flow of the Program in the Interrupt registers are correct.

Comment: We don't have your hardware to debug this issue. Are you sure the levels are the pin are as you expect? What debug have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all the mess, there is a input buffer 
SCU_PinConfigure(0xC,1,( SCU_CFG_MODE_FUNC4 | SCU_SFS_EPUN | SCU_SFS_ZIF |  SCU_SFS_EZI ));

There is a bit which is used to Enable the Input buffers.
After Enabling this bit, the input read  and interrupts are enabled.
Thanks for the Reply,
May this answer will help for solving the Gpio inputs read and enabling the interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same problem as you several months ago. I set the GPIO in input-interrupt mode, but I couldn't set the ISR. I suggest you check your code by following steps:

1. check the interrupt source signal. Make sure it works.
2. print the important variate and register to observe whether it is right.

If both of two steps are right, it proves that GPIO is in input-interrupt mode. If it can't get the ISR, find out where it goes. There must be some problems that occur in the process of hardware interrupt. The process is written by assembly language.

Comment: Have you checked the flow of the code. The external signal is Active LOW. When interrupt occurs